# porting ipython widget to newer ipywidget API

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was trying to port the [euroscipy2014](https://github.com/rossant/euroscipy2014) tutorial (which is also the base for the [ipython cookbook](http://ipython-books.github.io/)) to the newer ipywidget API. I succesfully converted 3 of the 4 notebooks following the directions I found on the relative [ipython documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/whatsnew/version3_widget_migration.html) but i'm having troubles in porting the 3rd notebook ([03_custom.ipynb](https://github.com/rossant/euroscipy2014/blob/master/03_custom.ipynb)).

I changed the js code from:

```
%%javascript
// We import the WidgetManager.
require(["widgets/js/widget"], function(WidgetManager){ 

// We define the NumberSelector view here.
var NumberSelector = widget.DOMWidgetView.extend({

    // Function for rendering the view.
    render: function(){
```

to:

```
%%javascript
// We import the WidgetManager.
require(["widget"], function(WidgetManager){ 

// We define the NumberSelector view here.
var NumberSelector = widget.DOMWidgetView.extend({

    // Function for rendering the view.
    render: function(){
```

using `require(["widget”] …` instead of `require(["widgets/js/widget …` and `widget.DOMWidgetView.extend` instead of `IPython.DOMWidgetView.extend`
but when testing the widget at the code cell 4 I have (log from the js console):

```
Couldn't create a view for model id '8727d6f51f804c7aa582b3d95b3c630d'  --  Error: Class NumberSelector not found in registry (…)
```

I guess the last line in the js code:

```
WidgetManager.register_widget_view('NumberSelector', NumberSelector);
```

didn’t worked. (maybe `.register_widget_view` is no more a valid call).

Have you any idea on how to fix this? thanks!

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/rossant/euroscipy2014/issues/2) but i thought the proting of such API can be a topic of general interest, so i'm posting a question here as well.

https://github.com/rossant/euroscipy2014/issues/2

Comment: see if changing the "widget" to "@jupyter-widgets/base" works, I'm testing on ipywidget 7.0.0